# How to translate python tuple unpacking to Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, iterable-unpacking

I am translating some python code to Matlab, and want to figure out what the best way to translate the python tuple unpacking to Matlab is.

For the purposes of this example, a `Body` is a class whose constructor takes as input two functionals.

I have the following python code:

```
X1 = lambda t: cos(t)
Y1 = lambda t: sin(t)

X2 = lambda t: cos(t) + 1
Y2 = lambda t: sin(t) + 1

coords = ((X1,Y1), (X2,Y2))
bodies = [Body(X,Y) for X,Y in coords]
```

which is translated to the following Matlab code

```
X1 = @(t) cos(t)
Y1 = @(t) sin(t)

X2 = @(t) cos(t) + 1
Y2 = @(t) sin(t) + 1

coords = {{X1,Y1}, {X2,Y2}}
bodies = {}
for coord = coords,
    [X,Y] = deal(coord{1}{:});
    bodies{end+1} = Body(X,Y);
end
```

where Body is

```
classdef Body < handle

    properties
        X,Y
    end

    methods
        function self = Body(X,Y)
            self.X = X;
            self.Y = Y;
        end
    end

end
```

Is there a better and more elegant way to express the last line of the python code in Matlab?

Comment: So is the question about unpacking or class initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what `Body` is, this is my solution:

```
bodies = cellfun(@(tuple)Body(tuple{1},tuple{2}), coords);
```

or, if the output has to encapsulated in a cell array:

```
bodies = cellfun(@(tuple)Body(tuple{1},tuple{2}), coords, 'UniformOutput',false);
```

And just for testing, I tried it with the following:

```
X1 = @(t) cos(t);
Y1 = @(t) sin(t);
X2 = @(t) cos(t) + 1;
Y2 = @(t) sin(t) + 1;

coords = {{X1,Y1}, {X2,Y2}};

%# function that returns a struct (like a constructor)
Body = @(X,Y) struct('x',X, 'y',Y);

%# tuples unpacking
bodies = cellfun(@(tuple)Body(tuple{1},tuple{2}), coords);

%# bodies is an array of structs
bodies(1)
bodies(2)
```

Comment: When I actually implement Body in a seperate class file (see above), I get the following error:

??? Error using ==> cellfun
Body type is not currently implemented.

Error in ==> driver at 9
bodies = cellfun(@(tuple)Body(tuple{1},tuple{2}), coords);

Comment: try the second form with: `UniformOutput=false` to construct a cell array instead

Comment: @Dzhelil: The error you're getting seems like it's related to the `Body` class you've created. Have you checked that it is working correctly? Try this: `testBody = Body(X1,Y1)`.

Comment: Using `UniformOutput=false` as per Amro's suggestion solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [Amro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739566/how-to-translate-python-tuple-unpacking-to-matlab/1739681#1739681) will work for you. However, if you don't really need or want to create a new `Body` class, there's a straight-forward way to construct an array of structures using the [STRUCT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html) command:

```
X1 = @(t) cos(t);
Y1 = @(t) sin(t);
X2 = @(t) cos(t) + 1;
Y2 = @(t) sin(t) + 1;
bodies = struct('X',{X1 X2},'Y',{Y1 Y2});
```

In this case, each element of the array `bodies` is a structure as opposed to a class object, but you should be able to use it in much the same way.